# ¿Cómo obtener la primer variable más chica de un array con la función min?

Tags: php

Lo que quiero obtener es el nombre de la primer variable más chica de un array, no el valor.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php
$pj0=-1;
$pj1=1;
$pj2=3;
$min=min(array($pj0, $pj1, $pj2));
echo $min;
?>
```

> Salida: -1

Y lo que yo quiero es la salida sea el nombre de la variable, así:

> Salida: $pj0

Comment: Para que necesitas el nombre de la variable?

Comment: Para pasarla luego a una inserción SQL.

Comment: Porque no pasas la variable `$min`?

Comment: Justo iba a hacer la misma pregunta @alanfcm .

Comment: La cuestión es que cada variable contiene datos extraídos de columnas, tengo las columnas pj0, pj1, pj2 y necesito saber cuál de estas tres es la primer variable que contiene el número más chico. $min da resultado -1 y lo que necesito es el nombre de la variable. Sino se entiende, reformulo la pregunta.

Comment: No se entiende, mejor reformula la pregunta y pon los datos que estás manejando, incluso háblanos un poco de lo que ocurre antes, cuando creas las variables `$pj....`  me da que retrocediendo un poco en tu lógica se puede resolver hasta de una forma más sencilla. ¿Por qué creas tres variables y de dónde las creas? Si ya tienes un objeto estructurado se puede trabajar quizá ese objeto para obtener el valor mínimo en esa clave.